# Solving Logs different bases?

Tags: logarithms

I do not understand how $\log_2(x) + \log_4(x) = \log_2({x^{3/2}})$

Where does $^{3/2}$ come from? Naming the rules and steps would be helpful.

Comment: You mean $\frac 32$ not $\frac 23$

Comment: Yes I mean $\frac 32$

Comment: Look at the change of base formula?

Comment: I've tried, but I dont understand the logic. I also do not know if I am doing it correctly--- $\frac {log(x)}{log(2)} + \frac {log(x)}{2{log(2)}}$ ... What is next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\log_2x+\log_4x=\log_2x+\frac{\log_2x}{\log_24}=\log_2x+\frac12\log_2x=\frac32\log_2x=\log_2x^{3/2}$$

Answer (score 1):

A good property of logarithmic functions is:

$log_{a^n}b = \frac{1}{n}log_ab$

Proof:

$log_{a^n}b = \frac{logb}{loga^n} = \frac{logb}{n\cdot loga} = \frac{1}{n} \cdot log_ab$

In your example, $log_4(x) = log_{2^2}(x) = \frac{1}{2}log_2(x)$ and now, continue with the common properties of logarithms to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First rearrange your equation:
$$\log_2(x) + \log_4(x) = \log_2({x^{3/2}})$$
Now since $\log_2(x^c)=c\log_2(x)$ we have:
$$\log_2(x) + \log_4(x) = \frac{3}{2}\log_2(x)$$
Therefore
$$\log_4(x)=\frac{3}{2}\log_2(x)-\log_2(x)=\frac{1}{2}\log_2(x)\tag{1}$$

Now let $a=\log_2(x)$. Then $x=2^a$, and so $\log_4(x)=\log_4(2^a)=a\log_4(2)$, hence
$$a=\frac{\log_4(x)}{\log_4(2)}=\log_2(x)\tag{2}$$
or 
$$\log_4(x)=\log_4(2)\log_2(x)\tag{3}$$ 
But $\log_4(2)=b$ implies $2=4^b$, and so $b=\frac{1}{2}$. Therefore plugging this into (3) gives $\log_4(x)=\frac{1}{2}\log_2(x)$ as required by (1).